# how to run videos url coming in rss feed's description tag in windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I am creating a window 8 app. I have a rss feed url through which i am getting data in xml format. In the data i have description tag in which video url is present. but it is not working in embedded player. When I am opening the url in browser, a website is open and video play in that browser.

Can any one tell me how I can run video coming in rss feed. following is the example url that i have to play in embedded player in Windows 8 app.

http://www.cnn.com/video/#/video/world/2013/10/21/intv-wu-chesser-aus-fires.cnn

Comment: The link you gave is flash player based video. It may work with the use of WebView.

Comment: hii,I tried the webview but it is opening a page like we open in browser. But i need to play only video not other things that are coming

Comment: Then you need to fetch the embed URL for video, for youtube you can have embed URL like this http://www.youtube.com/embed/oDAw7vW7H0c